# Saved question queries?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, tag-filters

I use stackoverflow more and more and like the site but it's annoying to click through all my favorite tags and look for new questions. Is there a feature that lets me create and save a query like "show all questions not answered on these tags [..] within the last 3 days"? - Duncan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [StackExchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™](https://stackexchange.com/filters) to create a filter. You can add any tags you want on any sites. There's even a pre-made filter for all of your Favorite Tags on all sites you participate on, so you don't have to make it yourself. Through each filter, you can also sort by activity and newest and look at questions which have no answers.

Comment: Thanks I'll accept it when it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarks. Here's a link for [jQuery/Javascript questions which are unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+jquery?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50) which every single modern browser will let you save as a bookmark.

The [search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search) are quite powerful, you can produce a query for virtually anything and add it to your bookmarks.